# Pump control panel (electrical diagram attached). Could someone tell which ones of 1 2 3 4 5 6 are hots and which one are neutral?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Pump control panel (electrical diagram attached). Could someone tell which ones of 1 2 3 4 5 6 are hots and which one are neutral?

http://www.docdroid.net/zjph/wd-s115.pdf.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the ladder diagram included in the document, the odd terminals (1, 3, 5) are hot, and the even terminals (2, 4, 6) are neutral, more or less -- LS1 and LS2 are in series, though, so that's not *totally* true.  (Also, the assumption in the diagram is that you are using big, clunkin' mechanical limit switches, which obviously don't care which way around you wire them.)

Comment: Thanks so much! But could you explain how do you know that?

Comment: I mean - I don't seem to see any markings on the diagram.... Do you have to follow the current somehow from L1 to N?

Comment: Eh?  Are you looking at a different diagram than me @Dannyboy?  Because the markings next to the switch terminals for LS1, LS2, and LS3 are quite clear to me...

Answer (score 2):

They're all "hot". You're dealing with switches, so there's no "neutral".  You have an ungrounded (hot) conductor leading to the switch, and an ungrounded (hot) conductor coming back from the switch.

The switches are simply a way to open the circuit, so it doesn't usually matter which way they're installed.  When the switch is open, the circuit is open. When the switch is closed, the circuit is closed.

The grounded (neutral) doesn't come in until after the load.

Comment: Correct. The only thing that is "neutral" in that diagram is the circuit that connects to terminal "N" (for neutral... go figure) and run with white wire.